# Vectorizing prop.test over dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, vectorization, statistical-test

This is a basic question for which I am getting the following error.

> Error in prop.test: 'x' and 'n' must have the same length

with this code

```
cv_MH$pval <- (prop.test(x = c(cv_MH$search, cv_MH$against), n = c(size, size2)))$p.value
```

where `size` and `size2` are constant numbers that are large (>200,000).

This is what `cv_MH` looks like

```
search    against
45        23
384       274
657       883
```

Basically, I'm trying to create another variable within cv_MH that calculates the p-value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to repeat the counts (n) for each value in x.
What about this ?

```
cv_MH$pval <- prop.test(x = c(cv_MH$search, cv_MH$against), 
                        n = c(rep(size, length(cv_MH$search)),
                              rep(size2, length(cv_MH$against))))$p.value
```

x indicates the number of success (events of interest) and n the total number of events... x should have the same length of n, as suggested by your error message

Comment: yeah, that worked! why exactly did repeating the count work?

Comment: Briefly, the prop.function compares success rates, so you need to provide an equal number of numerators and denominators...

Comment: I thought I had 2 numerators and 2 denominators... (the numerators being `cv_MH$search` and `cv_MH$against` and the denominators being `size` and `size2`)?